# Does the Provider in useContext hold more than one value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

`<TodoContext.provider value={todos}>
</TodoContext>`

what if we want to have more than one value. Does the provider support that? Of course, we can add our values in the form of an object and append to the value but I just want to make sure if there is another way to add value to the provider.

Comment: you can pass them in the array

Answer (score 0):

Base on your project structure and design of components you can use nested context like below:

```
<FirstContext.Provider value={firstvalue}>
    <SecondContext.Provider value={secondValue}>
      <Component/>
    </SecondContext.Provider>
  </FirstContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. But is it the normal structure of the provider? it can't be any different than this? Just to make sure.

Comment: Its common when you want to get data from multiple parents